# magento showing wrong product count in category

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a strange issue and seems many are having the same on internet. Below picture will define my issue and also my magento version is 1.7

[image]

As I have highlighted, LEFT says the category has 16 products, but in actual the Category Products Tab shows 15 products. All my categories are messed up. Please let me know what's going wrong. I've tried disabling the cache, but it didn't worked.

[Edit]

I tried removing one-product from the category, then the number on the left went to 15 and total records 14. So I thought may be a product whose is disabled in there in this category. But when I searched for disabled products none were there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi product count comes from method name loadProductCount which is located at location `code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Collection.php`

If you will dig in deep this count is coming from a join query between two tables: `catalog_category_product` and `catalog_category_entity`

I have fixed this issue by using  event observer. you can do the same for time being. And let me know if you find any better solution.

```
public function deleteCountCategory (Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    try {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $productId = $product->getId();                     
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');    
    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalog_category_product');
    $query = "DELETE FROM {$tableName} WHERE product_id = ".(int)$productId;            
    $writeConnection->query($query);            
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;                   
    }
    return $this;           
}
```

Event used in config.xml

```
<events>
<catalog_product_delete_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
<observers>
<catalog_product_delete_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
<type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
<class>countfix/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
<method>deleteCountCategory</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
<args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
</catalog_product_delete_after_handler>
</observers>
</catalog_product_delete_after>
</events>
```

Comment: did you said you were having the same issue ?

Comment: Yes I was facing same issue in Magento 1.7 CE. Somehow after delete of product the entry was not getting removed from catalog_category_product  table.

Comment: Which event are you observing?

Comment: @roshanlal Did you make a custom module for this?

Answer (score 12):

This will fix them all.

```
DELETE FROM 
catalog_category_product 
where product_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM (catalog_product_entity))
```

Then, implement the solution in the observer to keep it from happening again.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to this is go to app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php

or it's better to create a local file so that it doesn't effects  while magento upgrade. So create
app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php

In this model create a new function say getFrontentProductCount()

```
    public function getFrontentProductCount()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addCategoryFilter($this);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);
return $collection->count();
```

}

Now go to your template phtml file where you execute your category product count. In general case it's: theme/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml

now call the above function as required, like:

```
 <ol>
            <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a> (<?php echo $_category->getFrontentProductCount() ?>)
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </ol>
```