# Magento showing wrong category product count in admin panel

Tags: php, xml, magento, phpmyadmin, magento-1.9.1

I am using magento-1.9.1

After deleting a product from admin panel, the product count of a category where it was linked to hasn't changed.

The solution of same problem described in [magento showing wrong product count in category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777478/magento-showing-wrong-product-count-in-category) did not help:

I created a `public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Collection.php` copying the original one from app/code/core and adding to it the suggested function "deleteCountCategory". I also created a config.xml with a suggested event and placed in the same directory as the modified Collection.php

This did not help.
What have I done wrong ? Or is this another issue of a newer magento version ?

Comment: Have you delete cache and reindex data ?

Comment: yes sure,deleted everything in cache folder, also did all refreshings and flushes in System -> Cache management

Comment: and also reindex data ?

Comment: yes. sure. I tried everything :)  but it did not change anything. in database table catalog_category_product there is still a record of a deleted product

Comment: Is product display anywhere like admin or frontend ?

Comment: Admin panel only, as it mentioned in the question I reffered to. The same problem exactly.

Comment: Since there is an entry in catalog_category_product, the delete operation might be interpreted. Because the product_id in this table is a foreign key referring to the product table - this row should have been deleted during the deletion.

Comment: iqbalmp, this is obvious how it should work, but not working.