# magento admin category product count wrong

Tags: magento

magento admin category product count wrong , in my admin category count is more that real product in that category how can it be fixed please guide , i am using magento 1.9.2.1

i check few older answer most of them deals with deleting database or some db query , but is it righ to do that please guide way to sort it out

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Magento admin question and belongs over on magento.stackexchange

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Magento admin question and belongs over on magento.stackexchange

Comment: @ShakirKhan instead of voting down you should have answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Magento but it will not create any issue at frontend.

In normal case, when you assign products to category then those products will be linked with that category and linked product count will be increased for that category. And if you unlink that product from that category then linked product count will be decreased.

Now problem will be arise when you delete product from catalog->product section. Still category will have entry for that product. So old product count will be in category.

If you want then follow below link.

[magento showing wrong product count in category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777478/magento-showing-wrong-product-count-in-category)

Hope you understood well.!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and just tested this. Without any issue, it works perfectly.

```
DELETE FROM catalog_category_product
where product_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM (catalog_product_entity))
```